# How to limit the Textbox size in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

In WP7 I am trying to limit the Textboxtext size.
Please guide me in this with sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can limit it by `Width` or `Height` property. In this case `TextBox` will be only with provided sizes.

Otherwise, you can set `MaxWidth` and `MaxHeight`. In this case Width and Height will automatically adjust by situation but not great than you specify.

`MaxLength` property can be used also. It limits the number of characters that can be displayed. `TextTrimming` handles how to trim text when it out of screen, i.e. add `...` in the end, for example.